# get link with javascript regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How can I get the first function parameter with javascript regex? For example, I have this element in the page and I want to retrieve the inline link when clicking on a tag.
sample:

```
<li><a href="#blog" data-rel="close" onclick="getRSSFeed('http://moi.ir/Portal/RssPage/ShowRss.aspx?CategoryID=541ac873-3706-4f31-97e7-5cd6d51170eb','BlogList');">news</a></li>
```

I want this text : http://moi.ir/Portal/RssPage/ShowRss.aspx?CategoryID=541ac873-3706-4f31-97e7-5cd6d51170eb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
onclick[^(]*\('([^']+)
```

Try this.Grab the groups 1.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/54